# UINavigation bar button background image size

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm trying sot set image background for the left back button navigation bar for all the app with this snippet:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
    if (version >= 5.0)
    {
        // iPhone 5.0 code here
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"btn_back.png"];
         image = [image stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:40.0f topCapHeight:0.0f];
        [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    }
    return YES;
}
```

I've been trying different values in stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: but best result was this:

[image]

How can I set background image to the correct size?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:` is deprecated. Use `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` instead.

This should work:

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 10, 1, 10)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```